# Printing Files in Reverse Order PHP

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

How can I print the files of a directory in reverse aplhabetical order? This is what I'm currently using:

```
foreach (glob("edit/news/*.txt") as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
}
```

The files are being printed in date-posted order, so the files are named like this:

```
20111214210118.txt
2011 12 14 21 01 18
Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure `rsort` is what you are looking for.

```
$files = glob("edit/news/*.txt");
rsort($files);
foreach($files as $filename) {
    include $filename;
}
```